# Dynamically change connection string for SessionManger without using factoryalias

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, castle

I am trying to use nHibernate and Castle and make a connection to one database based on the connection string stored in another database. Is there any way to change the connection string for SessionManager dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

the connectionstring is baked into the sessionfactory. i doubt that you can change it. you could create a lightweight factory to get the connection string or just use ADO.NET directly and then build up the real factory.